# Spring Boot Rest Service Form too large

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, jetty

I am using Spring Boot 1.3.2 and I need to expose a REST Web Service. To this web service I need to pass a String (that contains xml data) as parameter. The size of the string is usually between 2 MB and 120 MB. The problem is that I do not know how to configure the maximum size allowed for the REST method parameter and the default size is way too small. The Spring configuration must be in a java class, due to other dependencies. This is my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("eu.buzea")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories("eu.buzea.datamodel.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends Neo4jConfiguration {

    public Application() {
    }
    
    @Override
    public Neo4jServer neo4jServer() {
        return new RemoteServer("http://localhost:7474");
    }
    
    @Override
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return new SessionFactory("eu.buzea.datamodel.entities");
    }
    
    @Override
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public Session getSession() throws Exception {
        return super.getSession();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is how Rest endpoint looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public boolean processing(@RequestParam(value = "xml", required = true) String xml)
```

And when I send a String to the method I receive the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Form too large: 780963 > 200000
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractFormParameters(Request.java:365) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractContentParameters(Request.java:303) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.extractParameters(Request.java:257) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParameter(Request.java:826) ~[jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:70) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652) ~[jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577) [jetty-security-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515) [jetty-servlet-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257) [jetty-server-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544) [jetty-io-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555) [jetty-util-9.2.14.v20151106.jar:9.2.14.v20151106]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_71]
2016-04-26 20:32:44 [qtp2021854618-21] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser - badMessage: java.lang.IllegalStateException: too much data after closed for HttpChannelOverHttp@4d208ff0{r=1,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=}
```

Can anyone tell me how to set the (<strike>maximum request size</strike>) maximum form content size to be 200 MB or infinite?

**UPDATE**
The following post gives a solution in case you are using a jetty server, that is not embedded in Spring Boot: [stackoverflow.com/questions/3861455/form-too-large-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861455/form-too-large-exception)

I want to set the *maxFormContentSize* parameter, but I am not sure if it is an Eclipse parameter or a Spring parameter.

P.S. I know now how to solve the problem using MultipartFile Upload. Also, there is another option: to send the String/Data in the request Body. They both work great, but I want to know if it possible to set the *maxFormContentSize* in Spring  or Eclipse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Boot 1.4.0.M2 has a new property, `server.max-http-post-size`, that can be used to configure this. Milestones are available from https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone.

If you want to stick with Spring Boot 1.3.x, you can implement the same logic yourself by adding the following bean to your application's configuration:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer jettyCustomizer() {
    return new EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
            if (container instanceof JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
                ((JettyEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container)
                        .addServerCustomizers(new JettyServerCustomizer() {

                    @Override
                    public void customize(Server server) {
                        setHandlerMaxHttpPostSize(200 * 1024 * 1024, server.getHandlers());
                    }

                    private void setHandlerMaxHttpPostSize(int maxHttpPostSize,
                            Handler... handlers) {
                        for (Handler handler : handlers) {
                            if (handler instanceof ContextHandler) {
                                ((ContextHandler) handler)
                                        .setMaxFormContentSize(maxHttpPostSize);
                            }
                            else if (handler instanceof HandlerWrapper) {
                                setHandlerMaxHttpPostSize(maxHttpPostSize,
                                        ((HandlerWrapper) handler).getHandler());
                            }
                            else if (handler instanceof HandlerCollection) {
                                setHandlerMaxHttpPostSize(maxHttpPostSize,
                                        ((HandlerCollection) handler).getHandlers());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! Just as an advice for people who read this later: It is stupid idea to send this amount of data in request parameters! Better use the request body.

Answer (score 1):

When you deal with large files you should use multipart-file-upload.
[Spring 3.0 MultipartFile upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527837/spring-3-0-multipartfile-upload)

And client should send data to you in multipart format
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27097798/5649869

Comment: I have looked into MultipartFile upload and it may suit my needs. Creating a java client to send the data however is not that straight-forward. The post you suggested does not give me all the information I need. `map.add("file", new ClassPathResource(file));` and `template.get()` are too vague.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried increasing your HTTP POST maxPostSize?

In your `application.properties` file add:

`multipart.maxFileSize=20MB`

Documentation:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/MultipartProperties.html

If you want it in code here is the documentation:

[Increase HTTP Post maxPostSize in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232849/increase-http-post-maxpostsize-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Adding the application.properties file with this property didn't affect anything in my application. The second option you suggested is for a tomacat server...

Comment: The link is missed, please update it.

Answer (score 0):

For simple jetty-server-9.4.33.v20201020 without spring-boot. It worked by configuring this system property. The jetty uses `Integer.getInteger` function to get a default value on a static field `_maxFormContentSize` in `org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormContentSize", "20000000");   
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
```

For `spring-boot-2.3.5` only several values are overriden like `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties.Jetty.maxHttpFormPostSize` that can be configured with

```
server.jetty.maxHttpFormPostSize=20000001B
```