# ActiveMQ messages size or reference to object

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I want to pass a big message via ActiveMQ. There also two consumers/producers. The first one is built on Spring MVC and the second one uses Apache camel to get messages from queues.
The problem is that I tried to push a text message that contains about 10 mb of data, but ActiveMQ broker rejected it with an error message

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException:
>
> Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>
> Form too large: 10037142 > 200000

I know that there is an opportunity of using references to the objects that is stored in a FS, but I didn't find any libraries that could solve the problem.

Comment: Since you've solved the issue, could you please answer the question and accept that answer after 48h? That way the question will not show as unanswered and it will be easier for someone with a similar issue to see the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this error is on the producer client side but you can confirm this and depends on the client application type if it is a spring boot based or jetty, tomcat there are different way to resolve this limit, here example of solutions depending on your config [Form too Large Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3861455/form-too-large-exception) and [Spring Boot Rest Service Form too large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36872540/spring-boot-rest-service-form-too-large).
You can use BlobMessages too http://activemq.apache.org/blob-messages.html

Comment: Thanks for replay. I've have found out that this exception is thrown by jessy Web service. There is also no problem with sending a large message to activemq without references in a fs or blob messages. Anyway thanks for support.